# Xiaolin Wu antialiasing algorithm

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm trying to implement Xiaolin Wu antialiasing algorithm to draw smooth corners in my rectangle.
When I render rectangle with low radius I face the issue of outer pixel not being transparent. That is undesired behavior with input DrawRoundedRectangle(600, 300, 140, 140, 5, 0xEE222222). 0xEE222222 = RGBA(34,34,34,238): [image]

That is what I want to: [image]

As I understand it happens because I draw 8 pixel in iteration which causes a collision on low radius.
I am struggling to fix that issue in low radius and not breaking anything.

```
void DrawRoundedRectangle(int cx , int cy , int width , int height , int r, uint32_t color)
{
    uint32_t alpha1 , alpha2;
    const uint32_t color2 = color & 0x00FFFFFF;
    int x = r;
    int y = 0;
    float t = 0;
    while ( x > y )
    {
        const float curDist = 1.0f - fmodf( sqrtf( static_cast<float>( r * r - y * y ) ) , 1.0 );
        if ( curDist < t )
            x--;

        alpha1 = color2 | static_cast<uint8_t>( 127 * curDist ) << 24;
        alpha2 = color2 | static_cast<uint8_t>( 127 - 127 * curDist ) << 24;

        // top left
        dot( cx - y , cy - x + 1 , alpha1 );
        dot( cx - y , cy - x - 1 , alpha2 );

        dot( cx - x + 1 , cy - y , alpha1 );
        dot( cx - x - 1 , cy - y , alpha2 );

        // bot left
        dot( cx - x + 1 , cy + y + height , alpha1 );
        dot( cx - x - 1 , cy + y + height , alpha2 );

        dot( cx - y , cy + x - 1 + height , alpha1 );
        dot( cx - y , cy + x + 1 + height , alpha2 );

        // bot right
        dot( cx + y + width , cy + x - 1 + height , alpha1 );
        dot( cx + y + width , cy + x + 1 + height , alpha2 );

        dot( cx + x - 1 + width , cy + y + height , alpha1 );
        dot( cx + x + 1 + width , cy + y + height , alpha2 );

        // top right
        dot( cx + x - 1 + width , cy - y , alpha1 );
        dot( cx + x + 1 + width , cy - y , alpha2 );

        dot( cx + y + width , cy - x + 1 , alpha1 );
        dot( cx + y + width , cy - x - 1 , alpha2 );

        // last iteration only
        if ( y == x )
        {
            dot( cx - y, cy - x , color );
            dot( cx - x , cy + y + height  , color );
            dot( cx + y + width , cy + x + height  , color );
            dot( cx + x + width , cy - y  , color );

            dot( cx - y , cy - x - 1, alpha2 );
            dot( cx - x , cy + y + height - 1, alpha2 );
            dot( cx + y + width , cy + x + height - 1, alpha2 );
            dot( cx + x + width , cy - y - 1, alpha2 );
        }
        // skip 1st iteration
        else if ( y > 0 ) 
        {
            dot( cx - y , cy - x , color );
            dot( cx - x , cy - y , color );
            dot( cx - x , cy + y + height , color );
            dot( cx - y , cy + x + height , color );
            dot( cx + y + width , cy + x + height , color );
            dot( cx + x + width , cy + y + height , color );
            dot( cx + x + width , cy - y , color );
            dot( cx + y + width , cy - x , color );
        }


        t = curDist;

        y++;
    }

    // rectangle lines
    setColor( color );
    DrawLine( cx  , cy - r + 1 , cx + width + 1, cy - r + 1 );
    DrawLine( cx - r + 1 , cy , cx - r + 1 , cy + height + 1 );
    DrawLine( cx , cy + height + r - 1 , cx + width + 1, cy + height + r - 1 );
    DrawLine( cx + width + r - 1 , cy + height + 1, cx + width + r - 1 , cy  );

    // rectangle outer shadow
    auto half_opacity = ( ( ( color & 0xFF000000 ) >> 24 ) / 2 ) << 24;
    setColor( half_opacity | color2 );
    DrawLine( cx  , cy - r , cx + width + 1, cy - r );
    DrawLine( cx - r , cy  , cx - r , cy + height + 1 );
    DrawLine( cx + 1 , cy + height + r , cx + width + 1, cy + height + r );
    DrawLine( cx + width + r , cy + height + 1, cx + width + r , cy );
}
```

Comment: What are the red arrows illustrating? Is that undesired behavior or desired behavior? Can you provide an explicit input to your function that causes undesired output, the undesired output, and the desired output?

Comment: Edit your question with the details, please. Not in a comment. sorry for not specifying.